# pdf.js: looping through pages searching for text

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, pdf.js

I guess this is more of a question regarding how to use Promises correctly, which i don't grok:

According to this site (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript), we extract text from a page this way:

```
// assume pdf file has been loaded
function getPageText(pageNum, PDFDocumentInstance) {
    // Return a Promise that is solved once the text of the page is retrieven
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        PDFDocumentInstance.getPage(pageNum).then(function (pdfPage) {
            // The main trick to obtain the text of the PDF page, use the getTextContent method
            pdfPage.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
                var textItems = textContent.items;
                var finalString = "";

                // Concatenate the string of the item to the final string
                for (var i = 0; i < textItems.length; i++) {
                    var item = textItems[i];
                    finalString += item.str + " ";
                }
                // Solve promise with the text retrieven from the page
                resolve(finalString);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I want to search for a certain string through all the pages till i find the page with that string. i tried the obviously wrong way of calling the above function in a for loop, but didn't know how to end when the string was found.
Thanks for the assist!

Comment: `PDFDocumentInstance.getPage(pageNum)` already returns a Promise, wrapping that in a new Promise is an anti-pattern, give me a sec to fix your code

Comment: This should do it, hopefully: https://pastebin.com/cAvd9XBW

Comment: @ChrisG, appreciate you refactoring the code above - i'll definitely use your version - but it doesn't answer my question of how to search page after page of the document for a certain string.

Comment: Here's working code with a mockup of the text search: https://jsfiddle.net/69hjL4tc/ It uses a loop with `await` inside to search the pages in sequence. It's also possible to use Promise.all() to search all pages at once, btw

Comment: thanks again, @ChrisG. my js skills are quite primitive, despite my best attempts to understand the power of the language. this definitely helps move me forward. i do see the 1s timeout though, which may not be the most foolproof way of doing it?

Comment: That 1s timeout is just a mockup to simulate the actual async operation; the fiddle is only supposed to show how to run async calls in sequence until a certain condition is fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

here's a lame-ish attempt. it's recursive (wish it wasn't), and although it finds the text and gets to the resolve() call, i have no idea where execution goes from there, because it doesn't log to console as i had hoped:

```
  function findText() {
    var textToFind = document.getElementById('textToFind').value;
    findIt( 1, textToFind ).then( function( pageIndex ) {
      // the line below never gets called. i expected the resolve() method 
      // further down to come here.
      console.log( 'Found ' + textToFind + ' on page ' + pageIndex );
    },
    function(reason) {
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }

  function findIt( pageIndex, textToFind ) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
      if ( pageIndex > pdfObject.numPages-1 ) {
        reject("Couldn't find " + textToFind);
      }
      getPageText( pageIndex ).then( function( pageText ) {
        if ( pageText.indexOf(textToFind) === -1 ) {
          findIt( pageIndex+1, textToFind );
        }
        else {
          resolve(pageIndex); // in the debugger, i get here
        }
      });
    });
  }
```